# gesture recognizer on modal controller not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following library to present a view controller much like the native iOS music app: https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController

I can't seem to be able to drag the modal controller down. I have to tap the close button each time. I'm presenting it from a tabBarController.

```
let popupContentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController

popupContentController.popupItem.accessibilityHint = NSLocalizedString("Double Tap to Expand the Mini Player", comment: "")

self.popupContentView.popupCloseButton.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Dismiss Now Playing Screen", comment: "")
self.popupBar.barStyle = .prominent
self.popupInteractionStyle = .drag
self.popupContentView.popupCloseButtonStyle = .round
self.popupContentView.popupInteractionGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true

self.presentPopupBar(withContentViewController: popupContentController, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.popupBar.tintColor = appColors.darkBlack
```

Comment: It's likely the third party library specifics, but since there's been no comments/answers over two hours, I'll ask. Please, dumb things down for me - because I don't use this lib. What posted code do you think *should* drag the modal view down? Which actually does? Is `popupBar` the view that works or doesn't work? I'm guessing `popupContentView` and it's close button works. Are you trying to close `popupContentController` in some other way?

Comment: I had never used this Lib , Modal Controller is Controller that is being Dragged as shown there, Had you checked what other options are available in **popupInteractionStyle** Else can you share Xcode file ?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered here: https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController/issues/218

Another library was adding a gesture recognizer to the popup content controller's view, which caused a conflict.

Such conflicts can be resolved by implementing the interaction gesture recognizer delegate and allowing simultaneous work between the gesture recognizers.